# Подсчитать количество совпадающих значений в 2-х столбцах excel с использование Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, python-3.6

Я хотел бы получить подсчет всех значений в разных столбцах, что совпадают. Вот лучшее объяснение, у меня есть этот ДФ.

```
df= pd.DataFrame([['1112',1222, 324332, '3213'], ['1112',1222, 324332, '3213','213213213',3213','321323']]) 

df= df.rename({0:'col1', 1:'col1'}, axis=1)

df
```

Желаемый результат:

[image: результат]

Я уже пробовал различные комбинации с groupby, size и values_count, но мои знания с size и value_count не так расширены, так что, возможно, я что-то упустил.

Я также думаю, что это должно быть достижимо с помощью списка понимания, но если это возможно с помощью функций pandas, то это было бы лучше для времени процесса.

Comment: Почему в результате отсутствует количество совпадений для других значений? Приведите в вопросе желаемый результат в виде фрейма. В текущем виде непонятно почему количество совпадений указанно только в первой строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, то можно так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
  ['1112',1222, 324332, '3213'], 
  [1222, '1112',324332, '3213','213213213','3213','321323']
]).T
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2']
print(len(set(df['col1'].unique()) & set(df['col2'].unique())))
```

Вывод:

```
4
```

У вас в вопросе инициализация датафрейма и датафрейм на скриншоте, кстати, не совпадают, другой порядок следования данных.

Comment: "Холмс, но как??" Как вы поняли суть вопроса? :)

Comment: @MaxU Практика, Ватсон, практика! На самом деле не факт, что правильно понял )